# getSupportFragmentManager() error in onPostExecute()

Tags: android, android-fragments

How do you update a fragment from onPostExecute(), My onPostExcute is not in an activity class?

I've inlcluded my onPostExcute method below. getSupportFragmentManager() has a can't resolve error, I've also tried getFragmentManger() which I've seen as a possible solution, this also shows a can't resolve error.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    ExtractRecipeData data = new ExtractRecipeData();
    data.recipeName(result);

    RecipeListFragment mRecipeFragment = new RecipeListFragment();
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    mFragmentTransaction
            .add(R.id.activity_main_container, mRecipeFragment)
            .commit();



}
```

Comment: What us your Activity? `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: Also, don't say `doesn't work for me`, this is the best way to hide real error message, and let the answerer puzzled and misleaded caused by this hidden.

Comment: The MainActivity extends AppComptActivity. The class the onPostExcute resides in extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add a FragmentManager to the Constructor of your AsyncTask Class. Like:
class MyTask(FragmentManager fm) extends AsyncTask { ... }
then you can use it

Comment: I can't believe how long I've been searching for an answer and how easy this was to implement.